# I need r_basicprofile scope for my LinkedIn App

Tags: linkedin-api

As part of my app experience, after SSO with LinkedIn, I would like to provide users the ability to go back to their public profile page so need the vanityName field in the /me endpoint which requires  r_basicprofile scope. I’ve reached out to LinkedIn support but they’ve directed me here to StackOverflow. I really don’t know why I’m asking for additional permissions here, but here I am?

I’m finding the LinkedIn developer experience very taxing